# Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios

Tags: terminal, compass-sass, sass, zurb-foundation

I have foundation installed and when I edit and save the app.scss file it creates a "app.css" and a "config.rb" file in the sass folder of my project. when I open that "app.css" file I get this

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
```

and then under that I get this:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
          Load paths:
            /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WebApp02/sass
            /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
            /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
            Compass::SpriteImporter
    on line 1 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WebApp02/sass/_settings.scss
    from line 2 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WebApp02/sass/app.scss
```

and then a bunch of paths to my gems.

It never created an app.css and config.rb file in my sass folder before I was wondering if anyone can explain why that is happening. Compass still complies to app.css in the "stylesheet" folder but I would like to fix this to keep from any future errors from happening.

config.rb file looks like this

```
require 'zurb-foundation'
Require any additional compass plugins here.


Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
 output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
    relative_assets = true
```

Comment: What does your config.rb look like?

Comment: I added the config.rb content to the original question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having same error in my project with sinatra. It was after upgrading from foundation 3.2.5 to version 4.0.2.
I realized that 'foundation/common/ratios' is not in the zurb-foundation gem anymore.
I had another error on "foundation not found or unreadable" so I had to modify also my Gemfile requiring 'compass' gem before zurb-foundation

```
gem 'compass'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
```

With foundation 3.2.5 'compass' wasn't explicitly required in Gemfile, but now it is and if you look at the zurb-foundation.rb code (in your ruby gemset), you can see:

```
if defined?(Compass)
  Compass::Frameworks.register("foundation",
    :stylesheets_directory => File.join(root,"scss"),
    :templates_directory => File.join(root,"templates")
  )
end
```

For this reason if in the project compass is not defined before zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation.rb doesn't expand the path including the scss folder.

I hope that my experience of today, may help you.
Best regards,
   Roberto

Comment: Since 'foundation/common/ratios' is not in the zurb-foundation gem anymore...how must I handle this, I have the same issue. And I removed the 'foundation/common/ratios' import statement from the Foundation and Overrides file but now some of my styles are not applying correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I couldnt get this to work (rails 3.2.12 with asset pipeline and gem "compass-rails" and/or gem "compass") so I just locked onto 3.2.5

```
gem 'zurb-foundation', "= 3.2.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

i had these same errors when trying to update a foundation 3 website using visual studio **Express** 2010.  Express does not allow the use of the Mindscape extension tool.

so this is what worked for me a few times now.  i basically start with a new webfolder using compass to create the folder.  I don't waste my time trying to update because this seems to work for me. And its common to back up before a version update anyway.

from the root folder above your website.  (i use the vs default path)  so from the command line in rails  i cd to this  path

```
> cd C:\Users\georgegargoyle\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\
```

*note if you are ungrading from foundation 3, and you only use ruby for foundation, you very well could have an old version of sass which the new foundation will need.  i have not known it to hurt to just uninstall and reinstall sass

which is

```
>  gem uninstall sass
> 
> gem install sass
```

i think  if it asks you the version of sass and you do not know 
type the 5th option as text  not the number 5  ... all versions ??
then.. type the number 5
you may get two warnings so i just hit y or yes twice.

anyway, from the websites folder type

compass create yournewfolder -r zurb-foundation --using foundation

you should see cool   Woot!  there it is  then

```
> cd yournewfolder
```

to move into the project folder then

```
gem install compass
gem update compass
gem install foundation
gem update foundation
```

the documentation for foundation is below and i am new to this so this is not necessarily  best practice, just what worked for me.  Thanks to gekorob above I think i learned, which i suspected, that the order you run these commands matters because of the versions you have installed. ruby, compass, sass, foundation and visual studio.

Which i suspect can lead to problems if thinks get switched around . and would lead you here.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

hope this helps and that you see lots of this.

http://www.ipaad.org/images/Step105.jpg