# Compiling Foundation 5 without gulp but with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, compass-sass, assetic, zurb-foundation-5

I'm running a project where `Symfony2` serves the api and back-end; I use bower to install my front-end dependencies, including `Angularjs` and `Zurb Foundation`. We're using `Assetic`––a Symfony2 bundle––to minify, uglify, pre-render and combine our assets. We're also using `Sass` (as `.sass`), compiled by Assetic.

I want to work with Foundation's `_settings.scss` and understand that Foundation needs to recompile itself whenever I change a variable. I've tried running `compass watch path_to_file` but that doesn't update my Foundation project.

As I understand it, a lot of people run foundation using `Compass` or `gulp`. I've [read](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/using-sass.html) [through](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/global.html) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179990/how-to-use-foundation-5-with-compasssass) [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/) but am unsure how it relates to my particular case. One source suggests running `compass init` to start a project and that `compass watch` to update the project when I make changes, but that doesn't seem appropriate to do with Symfony2, but I may be wrong. Anyone got tips?

I'm using this foundation repo: https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation,
but there's also this one: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps. The second repo seems more suited for people who are running a Foundation project with `gulp`, the `foundation cli`, or by running `compass init` when starting a project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *incredibly* simple:

I use `Assetic` to compile my sass. It typically looks like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    "@SiteBundle/Resources/public/vendor/foundation/scss/app.scss"
filter="compass" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

`app.scss` is a file I created because that seems to be how everyone works with foundation. `app.scss` then imports the foundation components I want as well as `normalize.scss` and `_settings.scss`. I don't have to run `compass watch` because `Assetic` is already compiling for me.

I might move my `app.scss` and `_settings.scss` out of my vendors directory to ensure I don't write over either when updating foundation. But at the moment here's what my `app.scss` looks like, for anyone interested:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
// Foundation by ZURB
// foundation.zurb.com
// Licensed under MIT Open Source

// Import normalize and settings

@import "normalize.scss";
@import "foundation/settings";

// Make sure the charset is set appropriately

// Behold, here are all the Foundation components.
@import "foundation/components/grid";
// @import "foundation/components/accordion";
@import "foundation/components/alert-boxes";
@import "foundation/components/block-grid";
// @import "foundation/components/breadcrumbs";
@import "foundation/components/button-groups";
@import "foundation/components/buttons";
@import "foundation/components/clearing";
@import "foundation/components/dropdown";
@import "foundation/components/dropdown-buttons";
@import "foundation/components/flex-video";
@import "foundation/components/forms";
@import "foundation/components/icon-bar";
@import "foundation/components/inline-lists";
// @import "foundation/components/joyride";
@import "foundation/components/keystrokes";
@import "foundation/components/labels";
// @import "foundation/components/magellan";
// @import "foundation/components/orbit";
@import "foundation/components/pagination";
@import "foundation/components/panels";
// @import "foundation/components/pricing-tables";
@import "foundation/components/progress-bars";
@import "foundation/components/range-slider";
@import "foundation/components/reveal";
@import "foundation/components/side-nav";
@import "foundation/components/split-buttons";
@import "foundation/components/sub-nav";
@import "foundation/components/switches";
@import "foundation/components/tables";
@import "foundation/components/tabs";
@import "foundation/components/thumbs";
@import "foundation/components/tooltips";
@import "foundation/components/top-bar";
@import "foundation/components/type";
@import "foundation/components/offcanvas";
@import "foundation/components/visibility";
```